# function not working using sql and tkinter (quiz)

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

On the function, `confirmAnswer`, it updates the question but doesn't display to the user whether their answer is correct or inccorrect which makes me think it is skipping straight to this line, `if self.Qn < self.recordNum['text']:` on the same function.

I only have two questions in the database at the moment allowing testing to be easier and when the question updates, the submit button doesnt work when an answer is inputted when really the quiz should end and display the score which is in the same function.

I included this much code as I thought it would make more sense to understand the code so sorry if it is too much and sorry if it comes across confusing. Thank you for your help!

```
def quiz(self):
    self.newf.pack_forget()
    self.head['text'] = 'Welcome to the psychology revision quiz'
    self.quizf.pack()

    self.quizScore = 0
    self.correctAnswer = ''  # <-- create it at start (and use better name)
    self.Qn = 1
    self.update_question()# <-- get new question
    self.update_question_number()
def update_question_number(self):
    # Get question's number

    query = "SELECT MAX(qnumber) FROM questions"
    c.execute(query)
    row = c.fetchone()

    self.recordNum['text'] = row[0]

def update_question(self):
    # Get new question

    query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
    c.execute(query, (self.Qn,))
    row = c.fetchone()

    self.question['text'] = row[1]

    self.answer1['text'] = row[2]
    self.answer2['text'] = row[3]
    self.answer3['text'] = row[4]
    self.answer4['text'] = row[5]

    self.correctAnswer = row[6]    

def confirmAnswer(self):
    self.rightOrWrong = self.enterAnswer
    if self.enterAnswer == self.correctAnswer:
        self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Correct"
        self.quizScore += 1
        self.update_question()
    else:
        self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Incorrect"

    if self.Qn < self.recordNum['text']:
        self.Qn += 1           # <-- get new question
        self.update_question() # <-- get new question

    else:
        self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Quiz Complete! Your score was: {}".format(self.quizScore)
```

Comment: Your questions lacks information on where / when / how `self.enterAnswer` is set. Have you tried printouts of the variables? e.g. printing `self.enterAnswer`, `self.correctAnswer` at the beginning of `def confirmAnswer(self)`?

Comment: I have this line in the def widgets, `self.enterAnswer = Entry(self.quizf, textvariable = self.confirmAnswer)` which links to `def confirmAnswer` and why would I print out those variables at the beginning of `def confirmAnswer(self)`

Comment: You are using a function instead of a StringVar as a textvariable? Based on which documentation / approach?You would print them out to debug your code. Code lines do not get "skipped". Use a `tk.StringVar` instead of a function first. btw - if you want to get the text do not use the Entry Widget. Use its `get` method. and please have a look at the documentation available and the object model of python / tkinter.

Comment: Okay I will try the things you have suggested, just to let you know I have this line below the `self.enterAnswer = Entry` line which is, `self.Submit = Button(self.quizf,text = "submit", command = self.confirmAnswer)`. I dont know if this makes a difference?

Comment: I could post my whole code if that helps?

Comment: Post a complete, Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. not your whole code. And yes, having a method assigned as textvariable is an issue. The Button binding to `self.confirmAnswer` is ok. Just one question as I am curious about it - have you ever programmed with python, especially tkinter before? If not, first try some simple things for the sake of your understanding of the OM of the framework. There are tons of tutorials out there.

Comment: I'm doing this program for my A-level computing, it was a big jump from GCSE and we were forced to use tkinter and sql without any help at all. I have watched many tutorials and not many help with this issue. I will take into account what you have said and try to fix the issue and will also search elsewhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Read tutorials, do not watch youtube videos on coding. Read Interface documentations.